# discord.py: How to get the id of a mentioned channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm coding a discord bot right now. But I have the problem that I don't know how to get a channel id of a mentioned channel.

How can I get the ID?

example:

```
def check(messagehchannelid):
     return messagehchannelid.channel.id == ctx.message.channel.id and messagehchannelid.author == ctx.message.author and messagehchannelid.content == (the channel id of the mentioned channel in the message)

messagechannelidcheck = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using command decorators:

```py
@client.command()
async def cmd(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    await ctx.send(f"Here's your mentioned channel ID: {channel.id}")
```

---

**Post-edit:**
You can use the `channel_mentions` attribute of a message to see what channels have been mentioned. If you're only expecting one, you can do:

```py
# making sure they've mentioned a channel, and replying in the same channel
# the command was executed in, and by the same author
def check(msg):
    return len(msg.channel_mentions) != 0 and msg.channel == ctx.channel and
    ctx.author == msg.author

msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check) # timeout is None by default
channel_id = msg.channel_mentions[0].id
```

---

**References:**

- [`discord.TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel)
- [`TextChannel.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.id)
- [`Message.channel_mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.channel_mentions)
- [`Client.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)

Comment: Sorry, I think I was a little inaccurate.
I'll edit the message with an example.

Comment: Edited my answer. Let me know if I missed something